# Resetting the order in schedules

Tags: c#, list, scheduling, revit-api

The goal of this macros (app) is to reset the order of elements inside of a schedule we have opened now. Order starts with a user chosen number. Numbers are stored inside every element's parameter that user can specify. We get IDs of elements by hitting "IDs of Selection".

[Resetting the order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJZn7.png)

```
public void AutoNumerate()
    {   
        Document doc = this.ActiveUIDocument.Document;
        ViewSchedule vs = doc.ActiveView as ViewSchedule;
        TableData tData = vs.GetTableData();
        TableSectionData tsDada = tData.GetSectionData(SectionType.Body);
        int startIndex = 1; //SETTING STARTING NUMBER

        using (TransactionGroup tGroup = new TransactionGroup(doc,"Numeration: "+vs.Name)) 
        {
        tGroup.Start();

            for (int rInd = 0; rInd < tsDada.NumberOfRows; rInd++) 
            {
                
            SetNum(doc,startIndex++,    );
                
            }
        tGroup.Assimilate();
        }
    }
        
        
        
    public void SetNum(Document doc, int num, List<Element> Myelements)
    {
        using (Transaction tr = new Transaction(doc,"Creating elements based on IDs"))
        
        {
        tr.Start();
            
            //List<ElementId> eleIds = new List<ElementId>{946164,946385,946484,946631,946708,946759,946816};
            int[] eleIds = {946164,946385,946484,946631,946708,946759,946816};
            
            
            foreach (int id in eleIds) 
            {
                
                List<Element> MyElements = GetElement();
            }

            foreach (Element ele in MyElements) 
            {
                //ele.LookupParameter("Comments").Set(num.ToString()); 
                ele.LookupParameter("Comments").Set(num.ToString()).ToList(); //SPECIFYING PARAMETER
            }

        tr.Commit();
        }
      }
    
    private List<Element> GetElementsOnRow(Document doc, ViewSchedule vs, int rowNumber)
    {
        TableData tableData =  vs.GetTableData();
        TableSectionData tableSectionData = tableData.GetSectionData(SectionType.Body);
```

Answer (score 1):

To sort a schedule you need to use the `ScheduleDefinition.AddSortGroupField` method.  Create a `ScheduleSortGroupField` from the `ScheduleFieldId` of the 'Comments' parameter to input into the method.